# Doc doesn't display the list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I've tried to define an example to display the list of acronyms. But after the compile step the doc only shows the text without a list of acronyms.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load the package
\usepackage{glossaries}

% Generate the glossary
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

%Term definitions
\newglossaryentry{utc}{name=UTC, description={Coordinated Universal Time}}
\newglossaryentry{adt}{name=ADT, description={Atlantic Daylight Time}}
\newglossaryentry{est}{name=EST, description={Eastern Standard Time}}

% Use the terms
\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt} and 10 hours ahead of \gls{est}.

%Print the glossary
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you run `makeglossaries --help` ?

Comment: @Fran where can I type this?

Comment: In the system command prompt, aka MSDOS windows (running `cmd ` in latest Windows versions, if a remember correctly... ) or a Linux terminal.  If you file is, said,  `xyz.tex`, the first run `pdflatex xyz`,  then  `makeglossaries xyz`, and `pdflatex xyz` again. Some  LaTeX editors can be configured to help you in this task.

Comment: @Fran here is the message: $ makeglossaries Thesis.tex
makeglossaries version 2.18 (2016-01-24)
Don't pass the tex file to makeglossaries:
either omit the extension to make all the glossaries, or specify one of the glossary files, e.g. Thesis.tex.glo, to make just that glossary.

Comment: Tip: "omit the extension". Do not  type `Thesis.tex`.  Just `Thesis`    .

Comment: Note that Windows usually hide the extension of the filename. If you see `Thesis.tex` really could be `Thesis.tex.tex`. The safer is  configure  Windows to show always the complete filename.

Comment: Ok fine. It creates a acronym list. Thanks. I have another template and there the list of abbreviations doesn't work! Here the other thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295555/how-to-display-the-list-of-acronyms